# Programmatic git status

Tags: git

Does anyone know of a git plumbing (definitely not porcelain) means of determining whether:

- there are edits in the repo since the last commit, and
- whether local HEAD is ahead of origin/HEAD

I am looking to determine this programmatically, hence the desire to not solve this with porcelain and various sed-fu.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Update: as [mentioned below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17517443/6309) by [toupeira](https://stackoverflow.com/users/132312/toupeira), you can use the `--porcelain` option of [git status](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-status) (since commit 6f15787, September 2009, git 1.7.0).

I mentioned in my answer "[What does the term porcelain mean in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6978402/6309)" that:

> Perhaps the meaning of `--porcelain` here is "produce output suitable for consumption by porcelain scripts"

**However, that won't show the ahead/behind information**: see "[What to add to “git status --porcelain” to make it behave like “git status”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19206816/6309)": for that, you would still need to use other commands: see "[How to know if git repository has changes that have not been synchronized with server?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6133968/6309)"

---

Initial answer March 2009

In porcelain command, a:

```
$ git diff HEAD
```

gives you the changes since the last commit (what you would be committing if you run "git commit -a").

A possible equivalent in plumbing command would be:

```
$ git ls-files -m
```

for listing all modified (working directory or index) files

---

If you create your repository by cloning someone else's repository, the remote "master" branch is copied to a local branch named "origin".  You get your own "master" branch which is not tied to the remote repository.

There is always a current head, known as HEAD.  (This is actually a symbolic link, .git/HEAD, to a file like refs/heads/master.)

run "git status" and analyze the output:

```
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 11 commits.
#
```

More details in the SO question "[Why is Git telling me “Your branch is ahead of ‘origin/master’ by 11 commits.” and how do I get it to stop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277077/why-is-git-telling-me-your-branch-is-ahead-of-origin-master-by-11-commits-and)"

Possible equivalent in plumbing command:

```
* git-for-each-ref
```

for listing all commits, but requires analyzing the output as well...

Again, [git ls-files could be used to produced the same result than a git status](http://www.jukie.net/~bart/blog/20070831142646).

```
git ls-files --exclude-per-directory=.gitignore --exclude-from=.git/info/exclude \
                    --others \
                    --modified \
                    -t
```

Comment: "git ls-files --exclude-standard ..." would be a bit simpler.

Answer (score 4):

`git status` now has a `--porcelain` argument for scripting purposes (as well as an alternative `-z` for machine parsing), this is preferred to `git ls-files` which doesn't show files added to the index.

Comment: From [the documentation for `--porcelain`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-status.html): "Give the output in an easy-to-parse format for scripts. This is similar to the short output, but will remain stable across git versions and regardless of user configuration."

Comment: It's not clear from the release notes about when the `--porcelain` flag was added, however.

Comment: I found it! I searched the Git log with `git log --grep "--porcelain" --date-order`, and they show that the flag was added in commit [`6f15787181a163e158c6fee1d79085b97692ac2f`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6f15787181a163e158c6fee1d79085b97692ac2f) on September 5th, 2009. Incidentally, `git tag --contains 6f15787 | sort -V | less` reveals that this wasn't actually released in a stable version until v1.7.0, which was on [Febuary 12th, 2010](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e923eaeb901ff056421b9007adcbbce271caa7b6).