# Git - Update older open feature branch

Tags: git, git-pull

After the holiday I would like to continue working on my open ticket. I already started working on a feature ("*feature/my-new-feature*") locally before the holiday. After one week my colleagues have already merged their features into the master. Since I want to avoid later merge conflicts, I want to update my feature branch. However, I am unsure which update strategy to use. Two approaches are going through my mind.

**1.**

```
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout feature/my-new-feature
git merge master
```

**2.**

```
git pull origin/master
```

Probably both strategies work. Are there advantages and disadvantages to both ways that should be considered?

Comment: Neither strategies will update `master` or update `feature/my-new-feature` with `master`

Comment: `git rebase master`

Comment: Rebase works, but also checkout master, pull master, checkout branch, merge master into branch.

Comment: @evolutionxbox You are compltly right. I forgot to pull after checkout to master. i edited my question. thanks for hinting me

Comment: Rebase will be the way to keep a clean feature branch, though.

Comment: @Marvin Before I do that, do I have to pull (update) the master first?

Comment: @MartinTTS yes. Otherwise you'll be rebasing onto an older version of master

Comment: I prefer `git switch feature && git fetch && git merge origin/master`

Comment: `git checkout feature/my-new-feature && git pull origin master:master` See [the explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53859568/7976758).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually rebase on master, i.e. replay my commits on top of the master:

1. add and commit everything in the feature branch,

   ```
   git add ...
   git commit -m "..."
   ```
2. update the local master,

   ```
   git checkout master
   git pull
   ```
3. rebase the feature branch on the master

   ```
   git checkout feature/my-new-feature
   git rebase master
   ```

What you are proposing in 1. is updating your master and merging it to your branch. It is not wrong at all but it can create messy history with merge commits. You can read about the difference e.g. here: https://blog.git-init.com/differences-between-git-merge-and-rebase-and-why-you-should-care/

Your 2. is updating your remote tracking branch and merging that into your branch (`pull` does `fetch` and `merge`). It does exactly what you asked for: get the state on remote and integrate it to your branch. But it is not what you usually want: update master and origin/master too. There is nice explanation here and here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18137512/12118546

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8690791/12118546

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I do to avoid conflicts;

- Checkout `master` and pull the latest of `master`.
- Checkout your `feature/my-new-feature` branch, and pull the latest of your feature branch if you need to.
- Create a new feature branch off your `feature/my-new-feature` branch, name it something like `feature/merge-from-master-into-my-new-feature-branch`.
- Using your IDE or Git tool, merge `master` into your `feature/merge-from-master-into-my-new-feature-branch`, and resolve the conflicts locally.
- Once all is ready, then commit and push your `feature/merge-from-master-into-my-new-feature-branch` changes.
- Create a PR from your `feature/merge-from-master-into-my-new-feature-branch` into your `feature/my-new-feature`.
- Review the PR, approve it and delete `feature/merge-from-master-into-my-new-feature-branch` as you don't need it any longer.
- Checkout `feature/my-new-feature` and pull the latest changes.
- At this point, you have all your latest master changes in your `feature/my-new-feature` branch and you are good to continue working on your changes.