# Git merge master without reverting commit

Tags: git

I'm trying to fix my git branches, here's what I did.

I had some code that should have been developed in a branch; however, I committed and pushed to master (commit A).

Then I went ahead and reverted that commit and also pushed the revert to master (commit B reverts A).

Then I created a branch off of commit A and continued my development (commit C and D). So this is what my tree looks like currently:

```
* D (HEAD -> branch_a, origin/branch_a) removed testing code
* C updated
| * B (origin/master, origin/HEAD, master) Revert "new code"
|/  
* A new code
```

I want to be able to cleanly merge this branch back into master. Normally what I would do is `git pull origin master` into my branch but I can't do that in this case because `master` has the revert of A.

What can I do in `branch_a` to make sure it will be able to merge back into `master` without losing my work?

Comment: Is it correct that you simply want to forget about `B` and want your history to look like `A -> C -> D`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 once I merge back to master, yes I essentially want to forget about `B`. The initial problem is that `A` never should have been on master in the first place, the only reason `B` is necessary is that so `A` is not on master until I'm ready for it to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After typing up the question I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14389086/953327) that happened to have a command in it which achieved the result I was looking for.

Since the only commit to `master` is B which is a commit that is unwanted on the branch, it is possible to merge `master` into `branch_a` using a strategy that keeps the changes in the branch in case of conflicts.

From `branch_a` run `git merge -s ours master` which will merge `master` into `branch_a` using `branch_a` versions in case of conflicts.

The result of this operation changes the tree to look like:

```
E (HEAD -> branch_a, origin/branch_a) Merge branch 'master' into branch_a
|\  
| * B (origin/master, origin/HEAD, master) Revert "new code"
* | D removed testing code
* | C updated
|/  
* A new code
```