# git fetch + git merge origin/master vs git pull origin/master

Tags: git, git-merge, git-pull, git-fetch

I thought git pull was like a git fetch + git merge. Being in branchA, I always do a git fetch and then a git merge origin/master. But today, being in a branchA, I tried git pull origin/master and it didn't work but doing a git pull origin master worked. Any thoughts?

Extra question, if an updated origin/master and the online version of master are the same, why bother to have origin/master, wouldn't it be more convenient to always work with the online version that is always updated, releasing us from the burden to alway be git fetching?

Comment: Could you explain how "it didn't work" ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Differences between git pull origin master & git pull origin/master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883840/differences-between-git-pull-origin-master-git-pull-origin-master)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+difference+origin%2Fmaster+origin+master

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I thought git pull was like a git fetch + git merge.

It is.  However, the syntax one uses with `git pull` does not match the syntax one uses with pretty much every other Git command.  This is due to history: `git pull` predates a number of improvements made in Git between pre-1.5 and post-1.6 Git versions.  (Note that Git is now at version 2.26, so this is truly ancient history, dating back to 2005 or so.  The oldest versions of Git that people still seem to use today are in the version 1.7 range—but when you run `git pull`, you're harking back to the pre-stone-age, dinosaur Git 1.5 era.)

> [but] I tried `git pull origin/master` and it didn't work [while] `git pull origin master` worked

That is because this is the special syntax just for `git pull`.

Read [the `git pull` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) carefully for exceptions (of which there are plenty), but in general, most of the arguments you pass to `git pull`, `git pull` passes to `git fetch`.  Just as you would not run:

```
git fetch origin/master      # wrong
```

you cannot run

```
git pull origin/master       # also wrong: this runs git fetch origin/master
```

You can, however, run:

```
git fetch origin master
```

Here `origin` is a *remote* and `master` is a *refspec* (see [the `git fetch` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch) for more about remotes and refspecs).  This specifically limits your `git fetch` operation to fetch only commits new-to-you that are on their `master`, so as to update *only* your `origin/master`.<sup>1</sup>

After the fetch is complete, `pull` runs `merge`, or if you so specify, `rebase`, on some set of branch-head commits.<sup>2</sup>  The general idea here—which goes back to that pre-Git-1.6 history I mentioned—is that, having fetched some commit(s) from some other Git, you now wish to *incorporate* those commits into your *current branch*.

There was a time, in early Git, when the entire concept of *remote* did not exist, and hence there were no remote-tracking names: there was no `origin` at all, hence no `origin/master`.  It was therefore important to incorporate their commits immediately, lest your Git run a garbage collection pass and *remove* the new commits you obtained.

In the post-1.6 era—i.e., since 2006 or so—it's been safe to collect the commits and *let them sit there* for a while, while you look them over, think about them, or even ignore them entirely for a while.  The *remote* name `origin` introduced the *remote-tracking* names, such as `origin/master`, which retains those commits indefinitely.  There is no longer any need for a mad rush of shoving those commits into one of *your own* branches, in order to prevent them from being removed.

The bottom line is: **If you find `git pull` convenient, use it.  If not, don't.  Remember that the arguments you'll use, if you use arguments, are unique to it.**  It's just a combination of `git fetch`, plus an immediate second command to incorporate some fetched commits into the *current* branch.  I find this *in*-convenient, most of the time: I like to *inspect* the fetched commits first.  **If you don't use `git pull`, you'll name the incoming commits with remote-tracking names like `origin/master`, but if you do use `git pull`, you *can't* use these names in the `git pull` command itself, because it is being compatible with ancient times when these names did not exist.**

---

<sup>1</sup>This kind of `git fetch` will update your `origin/master` in any modern Git, but in Git versions before 1.8.4, it will leave `origin/master` un-updated.

<sup>2</sup>The commits chosen as arguments to merge or rebase are those from references that you specifically named on the command line, if you named any.  Otherwise, the (single) commit chosen as an argument is the one corresponding to the *upstream* setting of the current branch.

In some corner cases, `git pull` runs something other than merge or rebase as its second command.  The most interesting of these special cases is pulling into a completely empty repository: here, neither `git merge` nor `git rebase` will do anything, so `git pull` essentially just runs `git checkout` instead.  This one special case obviously happens only once in any given repository.

Comment: If I do a `git pull`, it will `git fetch` (update my origin/x's) and `git merge` origin/master to my branch only. On the other hand, if I do `git pull origin master`, it will `git fetch` (update only my origin/master) and `git merge` origin/master to my branch only. Are these assumptions correct?

Comment: @user33276346: With no additional arguments—i.e., run as `git pull`—your Git will look up the *upstream setting* for your current branch. What branch are you on? What is its upstream? Break that up into its parts—e.g., `origin/master` becomes `origin master`—and the first part gives you the remote for the `git fetch`. Put them back together and they give you the remote-tracking name for the subsequent `git merge`. The fetch that `git pull` runs will be an "unlimited" fetch, updating `origin/*`.

Comment: But, with additional arguments—e.g., `git pull origin master`—your Git will run `git fetch origin master`, which is a limited fetch that just updates your `origin/master`. Then your Git will run the equivalent of `git merge origin/master`.

Comment: So if, say, you're on your own `feature/two` whose upstream is `origin/feature/two`, `git pull` would update `origin/*` and merge with the updated `origin/feature/two`, but `git pull origin master` would update `origin/master` and merge with the updated `origin/master`.

Comment: (See above for all the caveats about old Git versions predating 1.8.4 and the like.)

Comment: Awesome. So to summarize: `git pull` = `git fetch` + `git merge origin/branch`. Additionally, git pull and `git pull origin branch` only differ in that the latter will only "update" origin/branch and not all origin/* as `git pull` does. If so, THANK YOU #torek. I hope this helps others as it helped me.

Comment: Yes - though the summary misses tons of tricky little traps, such as things like ancient versions of Git behaving differently. Git 1.7.x and 1.8.x (for various x values) are still "out there" in some distributions, so these traps are sometimes important.