# Build error "file not found" after git pull --rebase origin master

Tags: c++, git

Remote repo has made some changes to project settings (added new folder and changed include path). How do I pull these settings into my repo please? I tried

```
git pull --rebase origin master
```

And then build the c++ codebase but the build throws "File not found". Appreciate any help this beginner can get.

Answer (score 1):

It is [indeed `git pull origin master`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2883857/6309) but:

- check first `git` is recognized in your current shell and `$PATH`

  ```
    git version
  ```
- check you are in your local repository

  ```
    cd /path/to/local/repo
    git remote -v
    git pull --rebase origin master
  ```

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't very specific - its the build that throws after pull. git is recognized. May be I somehow need to update include path in my local repo? Thanks for helping.

Comment: @user2696565 It depends from which folder the build is launched, and if the Makefile is using relative or absolute paths.